# Как перезапустить сервис через playbook ansible несколько разв

Tags: ansible

Мне нужно в плей буке повторить одну задачу несколько раз, перезапуск сервиса, для этого я пытаюсь использовать параметры `retries` и `delay` ниже задача:

```
-name: Restart service zabbix-agents
  service:
    name: zabbix-agent
    state: restarted
  retries: 3
  delay: 10
```

Но сервис не перезапускается. Loop, как я понял используется для выполнения задачи несколько раз с разными параметрами, но мне не нужно выполнение с параметрами, нужно просто перезапустить сервис несколько раз. Registred так же не подходит (если я правильно понял), т.к. сервис корректно запускается с первого раза и статус у него "успех".

Comment: Первое замечание, отфарматируйте таск в вопросе, чтоб его можно было быстро читать - не в строчку, а как в YML вайле. Второе замечание - в модуле `service` нет опции `delay`  о чем вам сообщение об ощибке и пытается донести.  Почитайте описание модуля https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/service_module.html и https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/systemd_module.html перепишите такск и прогоните снова.

Comment: Как отредактировать формат, я пробовал, у меня все равно в одну строчку? Второе, да, моя ошибка, некорректно описал задачу, исправил.

Comment: `retries` включается после НЕ успешного выполнения задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Первыая строчка в Google, но доавблю сюда.

`loop`

> Loops
>
> Often you’ll want to do many things in one task, such as create a lot
>   of users, install a lot of packages, or repeat a polling step until a
>   certain result is reached.

Вольный перевод:

Частенько вам нужно выполнить несколько вещей в одном заданиии (таске), как создание нескольких пользователей, установка множества пакетов или выполнине выбора пока не будет достигнут определенный результат.

Но думаю у вас ошибка в сдвиге самого`retries` и `delay`

```
- name: "Restart service zabbix-agents"
  service:
    name: zabbix-agent
    state: restarted
  retries: 3
  delay: 3
```

Так же стоит обратить внимание на такую вещь как  `handlers` в `roles` которые запускаютс по определенному событию (вы изменили файл ностройки, доавили бд, пересоздали пользователя. ждете отклика от другого сервиса). Они будут игнорится если не было никаких изменений, что экономит время на отработку плейбука или роли или такса.

---

`retries` - запускать после НЕ успешного выполнения задачи

Как вариант, использовать `with_items` и `loop_control` (описано в документации), повторить перезагрузку  сервиса 3 раза, задержкой после каждой итерации на 3с:

```
- name: "Restart service zabbix-agents 3 times"
  service:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: restarted
  with_items:
      - zabbix-agent
      - zabbix-agent
      - zabbix-agent
  loop_control:
      pause: 3
```

**Ссылки**

- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/modules/wait_for_module.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.5/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html
- https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change

Comment: Спасибо, моя ошибка, некорректно описал задачу, сейчас отредактировал.

Comment: @AntonMarc обновил ответ, нашел решение, нужно использовать `with_items` и `loop_control`